Trapped in cave filled with water, with snakes and crocodile
From memory, I think it was an adventure movie in the 80's. It was in English.
As I remember watching it the first time while growing up. The only scene I can remember was when both the actor and actress (who's wearing a long white dress) are trapped in some sort of a cave or a space filled with water and there's a lot of small snakes and crocodile swimming past them while they tried to escape. 
I have been searching for this however no luck until now. Anyone?

Was it in English? Do you remember what these characters looked like? Or the genre\atmosphere? (Horror? Light adventure flick?)

OK. Incorporated into the question.

Could it be Romancing the Stone? Kathleen Turner wears a long off-white dress and encounters a snake.



There's also a watery cave and plenty of crocodiles.

This was my first thought.
